I would like to know what causes the font on my website to change completely because of this html code integrated into adobe muse?
I have a code for accordion (FAQ) but when embedded in Adobe muse that make other font changing.


if (jQuery(".toggle .toggle-title").hasClass('active')) {
  jQuery(".toggle .toggle-title.active").closest('.toggle').find('.toggle-inner').show();
}
jQuery(".toggle .toggle-title").click(function() {
  if (jQuery(this).hasClass('active')) {
    jQuery(this).removeClass("active").closest('.toggle').find('.toggle-inner').slideUp(200);
  } else {
    jQuery(this).addClass("active").closest('.toggle').find('.toggle-inner').slideDown(200);
  }
});
//# sourceURL=pen.js
.container {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

body {
  color: #00A89A;
  font-family: Mikado, sans-serif;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
}

span {
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  font-weight: 450;
}

p {
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.toggle:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00A89A;
}

.toggle .toggle-title {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border-top: 1px solid #00A89A;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.toggle .toggle-title h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.toggle .toggle-inner {
  padding: 7px 25px 10px 25px;
  display: none;
  margin: -7px 0 6px;
}

.toggle .toggle-inner div {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.toggle .toggle-title .title-name {
  display: block;
  padding: 25px 25px 14px;
}

.toggle .toggle-title a {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
<script>
  window.console = window.console || function(t) {};
</script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="toggle">
    <div class="toggle-title">
      <h3>
        <span class="title-name">C’est quoi une farine d’agriculture raisonnée ?</span>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="toggle-inner">
      <p>L'agriculture raisonnée est un mode d'agriculture prenant en considération le respect de l'environnement et de la santé du consommateur. Une farine issue de ce type d’agriculture est donc bonne pour vous et notre Belle Province.</p>
      <img src="https://static.lebulletin.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/Moulins-de-Soulanges-HRZ.png" alt="Moulins" style="width:80%;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END OF TOGGLE -->
  <div class="toggle">
    <div class="toggle-title">
      <h3>
        <span class="title-name">Utiliser du malt, ça sert à quoi ?</span>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="toggle-inner">
      <p> Le malt est une céréale germée (généralement de l’orge) ce qui la rend plus riche en nutriments. Nous utilisons du malt car il est plus riche en protéines et fibres que des céréales classiques.</p>
      <img src="https://d1ynl4hb5mx7r8.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/27164517/347566170.logo-horiz-2021-blancfondnoir-moyen.png" alt="LTM" style="width:60%;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END OF TOGGLE -->
  <div class="toggle">
    <div class="toggle-title">
      <h3>
        <span class="title-name">Une huile « oléique » c’est quoi ?</span>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="toggle-inner">
      <p>Le terme oléique vient de l’acide gras oléique, aussi appelé oméga-9. Pour se qualifier d’oléique, une huile doit en contenir 75% minimum. C’est donc une huile riche en oméga-9.</p>
      <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/d8cace_d7b90ee73650402f97f02e8e48c25136~mv2_d_2134_1566_s_2.png/v1/fit/w_2500,h_1330,al_c/d8cace_d7b90ee73650402f97f02e8e48c25136~mv2_d_2134_1566_s_2.png" alt="Arome-des-champs" style="width:80%;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END OF TOGGLE -->
  <div class="toggle">
    <div class="toggle-title">
      <h3>
        <span class="title-name">Pourquoi favoriser le sirop d’érable biologique ?</span>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="toggle-inner">
      <p>Pour protéger l’environnement et le consommateur, tout simplement. La production biologique minimise la dégradation et l’érosion du sol, réduit la pollution… <br>
        <br>Par exemple : un maximum de 3 entailles est autorisé par arbre. Également, tout l’équipement de grade alimentaire alors qu’en non-biologique personne ne vient vérifier si l’équipement est alimentaire.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END OF TOGGLE -->
  <div class="toggle">
    <div class="toggle-title">
      <h3>
        <span class="title-name"> Pourquoi nous utilisons du chanvre ?</span>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="toggle-inner">
      <p>Le chanvre est une protéine complète, c’est-à-dire qu’elle contient tous les acides aminés nécessaires au corps humain. C’est également très riche en protéines. C’est pourquoi, notre saveur Fauxmage est la plus protéinée.</p>
      <img src="https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C4E0BAQEZ0PMF-pu-rA/company-logo_200_200/0/1630587795746/aliments_trigone_inc_logo?e=2147483647&v=beta&t=0U36p8vALKs_Xu_EaHVf0MqvPWdl6tSSipwPxMFWQI0" alt="Aliments-trigone" style="width:40%;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END OF TOGGLE -->
  <div class="toggle">
    <div class="toggle-title">
      <h3>
        <span class="title-name">Et les autres ingrédients ?</span>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="toggle-inner">
      <p> Le reste de nos ingrédients est exempt d’additifs, de conservateurs, colorants ou autres intrants chimiques. Nous tenons à vous offrir un produit sain et respectueux de l’environnement.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END OF TOGGLE -->
</div>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>



